# AutoMapper 9.0 : AutoMapperMappingException: 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am working with a WCF Service and have setup DI with AutoFac and also wish to use automapper. I believe I have the injection(s) correct as I can see my configurations when I get into the service wish to call.

In my global.asax file I have this configuration;

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ProposalService>().As<IProposalService>();
        builder.RegisterType<ProposalListService>().As<IProposalListService>();
        builder.RegisterType<ProposalContext>().As<IProposalContext>();
        builder.RegisterType<GetProposalListRequestProfile>().As<Profile>();
        builder.Register(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            foreach (var profile in c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>())
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(profile);
            }

        })).AsSelf().SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(c.Resolve)).As<IMapper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();


        AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();
    }
```

In the Service I wish t use I have this

```
public class ProposalListService : IProposalListService
{
    private IProposalContext _proposalContext;
    private IMapper _mapper;

    public ProposalListService(IProposalContext proposlContext, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _proposalContext = proposlContext;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public getProposalListResponse GetProposalList(getProposalListRequest request)
    {
        var mappedRequest = _mapper.Map<getProposalListRequest, Data.Models.getProposalListRequest>(request);
        var result = _proposalContext.GetProposalList(mappedRequest);
        var mappedResponse = _mapper.Map<Data.Models.getProposalListResponse, getProposalListResponse>(result);
        return mappedResponse;
    }
}
```

And the mapping profile I have this

```
public class GetProposalListRequestProfile : Profile
{
    public GetProposalListRequestProfile()
    {
        IMappingExpression<Data.Models.getProposalListRequest, getProposalListRequest>
            mappingExpression =
                CreateMap<Data.Models.getProposalListRequest, getProposalListRequest>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.getProposalList, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.getProposalList));

    }
}
```

The structure is

The WCF Service is going out to a class library and is then going to call EF to get the data, however when I get to line `var mappedRequest = _mapper.Map<getProposalListRequest, Data.Models.getProposalListRequest>(request);` I get error

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'

I  would be grateful for any and all help on resolving this issue please.

Thanks

Comment: You've mapped from `Data.Models.getProposalListRequest` to `getProposalListRequest` but not the other way round. You need to create maps for both directions if you are going to map both ways.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#autofac

Comment: @Charleh I have tried with both, and swapping them round and reverse map and still get the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will check the [`CreateMap`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/IProfileExpression.cs#L24) method you will see next:

```
IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();
```

So your `CreateMap<Data.Models.getProposalListRequest, getProposalListRequest>()` will create map from `Data.Models.getProposalListRequest` to `getProposalListRequest` so to handle your use-case you will either add the reverted registration or try adding `.ReverseMap()` call after `CreateMap`.

Comment: Set breakpoint in the MapperConfiguration registration and check if any profiles are actually found. Then check IMapper registration.

Comment: @SimonPrice also I would just register the mapper itself as single instance and create configuration manually: `builder.Register(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfiles(new [] {new GetProposalListRequestProfile()})).CreateMapper() ).As<IMapper>().SingleInstance()`

Comment: can you provide a fuller example of what you mean as I will be creating a large number of mappings i suspect as the WSDL file that we have just taken over has 259 classes that may need mapping

Comment: @SimonPrice your current approach only makes more code to register all that mappings.   You can try to use [assembly scanning](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration) to register profiles from assemblies not by hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215579/discussion-between-simon-price-and-guru-stron).